# A link that when clicked displays a message

Tags: javascript, jquery, hyperlink

How can I make a link that when it is clicked, it displays a message?

Please show me how with JQuery or JavaScript.

Thanks to everyone!

Comment: How do you want to display? A pop up?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp

Comment: display an alert box or a page-in message (for example in a dive)? which one?

Comment: @Nick, I think user23557676 just wanted it to show it in general.

Comment: -1: agree with esqew. This forum isn't for getting people to write code for you.

Comment: @maxedison this isn't a forum ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is:

```
<script language="javascript"> 
function toggle() {
    var ele = document.getElementById("toggleText");
    var text = document.getElementById("displayText");
    if(ele.style.display == "block") {
            ele.style.display = "none";
        text.innerHTML = "Show/Hide";
    }
    else {
        ele.style.display = "block";
        text.innerHTML = "Show/Hide";
    }
} 
</script>

<a id="displayText" href="javascript:toggle();">Show/Hide</a>
<br><br>
<div id="toggleText" style="display: none">This is a hidden message.</div>
```

Comment: Why are you changing the html to Show/Hide everytime?

Answer (score 0):

You should clarify your question to detail *exactly* what you require.

In the meantime, here's one way of doing it:

```
<a onclick="alert('a message')">click me</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
<a href="javascript:alert('your message here');return false;">Link Text</a>
```